# Adding values to column that meet specific qualification

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble understanding this problem on my homework.

Context: I've created a flat-file table (titled `Users`) with columns (`UserId, Firstname, Lastname, Email, Points, PointsPlus`).

The problem states:

> Using the email column, add 15 points (in your pointsplus column) to all rows that have @aol.com in the email column

All of my emails had `@aol.com` in them, so I did:

```sql
Update Users
Set PointsPlus=15;
```

However, this was incorrect.

Comment: You set them to 15 rather than adding 15. Also how do you know that nobody inserted a row with gmail.com in between you checking and the update running? The query itself should check this

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you need to use:

```
Update Users 
Set PointsPlus = PointsPlus + 15
where Email like '%@aol.com'
```